# Why does JQuery require me to explicitly dequeue a queued image fadeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srbeckle/cnL1p48k/1/)

that demonstrates the queueing of some simple JS functions.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>

.div1 {
    height:300px;
    width:20%;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

</style>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<img class="image" style='width: 30%; height: 30%' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>
<button type="button" onclick="doStuff()" name="do">Do it</button>

</body>
<script>
function doStuff()
{
     var body = $('body');
     body.clearQueue();
     body.queue(function(){
         console.log('here');
         body.css("background-color", "yellow");
     });

     var div1 = $('.div1');
     div1.clearQueue();
     div1.queue(function(){
         div1.css("background-color", "green");
     });

     var image = $('.image');
     image.clearQueue();
     image.queue(function(){
         $(this).fadeOut(3000)});
     //image.dequeue();  //image doesn't fade without this step
}

</script>
</html>
```

Notice that when the button is clicked, the body and div1 colors change as expected. However, unless I uncomment the dequeue statement for the Google image fade, the image doesn't fade. I'm curious as to why I don't have to explicitly dequeue the first two operations for them to take effect, yet with an image fade, I have to call the dequeue method.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve by explicitly doing those operations via the animation queue?  Like, why don't you just do `image.fadeOut(3000);` directly?

Comment: @Pointy sure, that would work but I'm working on a web page where I have to queue up several operations before executing them later. In the process of the design I noticed this behavior and need to understand it before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

In the first two cases, the functions you're adding to the queue perform operations that don't do anything having to do with the animation queue. The callbacks that change colors do what they do immediately, and then they're done.

With the callback you're using for the image, however, the operation you request in the callback **does** involve the animation queue. Because the callback you pass does not call `.dequeue()` like a good animation callback should, the `.fadeOut()` operation won't be invoked.

If you add the `.dequeue()` *inside* your callback, then it works:

```
 image.queue(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(3000).dequeue();
 });
```

The call to `.fadeOut()` says, "add the fade-out operation to the queue".  By then calling `.dequeue()`, your callback is declaring itself finished, so the animation can proceed to the next step: the fade-out.

You can also write your code to make use of the callback jQuery passes to your custom animation function:

```
 image.queue(function(next) {
     $(this).fadeOut(3000);
     next();
 });
```

Comment: @Pointy...one more question then? I updated the JSfiddle to change the color of the body and div a second time, yet they have no effect. Any idea why? I have to dequeue those operations for them to appear. Confusing...

Comment: @swingMan any animation function you put on the queue **must** explicitly announce to the animation mechanism that it's finished, either by calling `.dequeue()` on the appropriate selector or by using the `next` callback. If you queue up a function that doesn't do that, then it clogs up the animation queue.

Comment: Thanks much Pointy. Very good to know. Wish my book explained it as well as you have. +1.